# linux kernel : completely fair scheduler : epoch length

Tags: linux-kernel

is it possible to know when a new epoch starts ?? and for how long the epoch is going to run  in linux kernel ??

I want to do some computation based on the length of epoch when a new epoch start..

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as a new unix epoch... The Unix Epoch started on January 1st, 1970, and keeps on increasing per second.
There is no new epoch scheduled, on the contrary, on november 20th, 2286, the tenth billenium of the Unix epoch will be celebrated.
More info:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time

Comment: I am talking about the epoch in "completely fair scheduler" of linux kernel.
check the link http://oreilly.com/catalog/linuxkernel/chapter/ch10.html
"In a single epoch, every process has a specified time quantum whose duration is computed when the epoch begins."